# How to easily import aerial imagery into gvSIG?

Tags: imagery, aerial-photography, gvsig

I have used ArcView GIS 3.x for years. I have decided to try some of the free GIS desktop software. I am now trying gvSIG. One feature I was hoping for was the importation of aerial imagery relatively easily. In the past I would download tiles of images from various repositories but now want to work like I am in Google Earth and simple have nice aerial images easily available for various regions that I am focusing on. In particular I am working with New York State and Google earth aerial images would be perfect. Can anyone help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid yo can not import a folder of tiles recursively. In gvSIG 2 that will be quite easy to perform. Right now you can load any number of files from a particular folder with the typical "add data" dialog.